# Can't seem to access an object's properties

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I have a simple function:

```
function myFunction($this){
    var_dump($this);
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
object(MyClass)#810 (20) {
  ["course_id"]=>int(43)
  // ...more properties
}
```

However, if I try to access "course_id" on the object, nothing gets output:

```
    var_dump($this->course_id);
```

In the class definition, `course_id` is public:

```
class MyClass extends AnotherClass {

    public $course_id = 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: If you post the full classes we might see something wrong there.

Comment: From what context are you calling `var_dump($this->course_id);`?

Comment: @bcmcfc from within the same function I listed at the top. This is in a plugin modifying a WordPress admin table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're using the name `$this` which is a pseudo-variable that becomes available when a method is called from within an object context, but you're not calling it within an object context, you're calling it from within a function context.

Change the parameter name and it works:

```
class MyClass {
    public $course_id = 0;
}

function myFunction($temp) {
    var_dump($temp->course_id);
}

$test = new MyClass();
myFunction($test);
```

Comment: Oh duh! Thank you so much. I used $this because that's what WP was handing me for the callback, and didn't even think about it. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Cheers!